# Passing result array to controller in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model, controller

I am developing a simple profile page but I am having a little dificulty passing the result array to the controller..am not sure if this how to do it.

Model:

```
 class Login_model extends CI_Model{

 function get_profile()
{

    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $query = $this->db->get('user');

    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
}
```

Controller:

```
         class Login extends CI_Controller {
         function show_profile{
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $q['user'] = $this->login_model->get_profile();
       echo $q['user'];
       }
      }
```

I tried to echo out $q['user'] as a tests to see if it will work, but it did not work.

Comment: If there are not empty result set it is either object either (in your case here too) an array. `echo` language construct can't handle those. Debug it with `var_dump($q['user'])`.

Answer (score 0):

in this context a result array would be if you were getting back more then one result. since you are only getting back one result you can do row_array() so like

```
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
{
    return $query->row_array();
}
    else
{
    return false; 
}
```

NEVER do this

```
// example of what NOT to do 
$this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));// NO NO NO
```

**validate the email first using codeigniter form validation** and then send it like

```
// if no user comes back then deal with it right away 
if( ! $user = $this->login_model->get_profile($email) ) 
{
    $this->showNoUserFor($email) ; 
} 
else 

{  // carry on....
```

otherwise - do the tutorial first in the codeigniter manual, it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot echo $q['user'] because it is an array. Use

```
`print_r($q['user']); exit;
```

and you can pass this to your view page by

```
`$this->load->view('yourViewPage',$q);
```